# Cannot reverse a List<T> inside foreach

Tags: c#

I have a `List<T>` which I need to reverse, so I tried:

```
foreach (Round round in Competition.Rounds.Reverse())
{

}
```

This return the following error:

```
the foreach statement can not work with variables of type 'void' 
   because 'void' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It would be worth clarifying in your question whether you really mean "which I need to reverse" or "which I need to iterate over in reverse order, without modifying the list".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two `Reverse` methods to consider:

- The instance method [`List<T>.Reverse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.reverse) reverses the list in-place, but has a `void` return type.
- The extension method [`Enumerable.Reverse<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse) does *not* modify the data source, but returns a reversed "view" of the data.

The compiler only looks for extension methods after it's exhausted instance methods - so in this case, it's binding to the `List<T>.Reverse()` method... which is why it's failing to compile. (You can't iterate over `void`.)

If you want to modify the list, just call the method separately:

```
Competition.Rounds.Reverse();
foreach (Round round in Competition.Rounds)
{
    ...
}
```

If you *don't* want to modify the list, the simplest approach is probably to call `Enumerable.Reverse<T>` directly:

```
foreach (Round round in Enumerable.Reverse(Competition.Rounds))
{
    ...
}
```

Or you could effectively "lose" the compile-time type of `List<T>`, e.g. like this:

```
// Important: don't change the type of rounds to List<Round>
IEnumerable<Round> rounds = Competition.Rounds;
foreach (Round round in rounds.Reverse())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reverse returns void, instead do:

```
Competition.Rounds.Reverse();
foreach (Round round in Competition.Rounds){...}
```

or if you don't want to modify `Competition.Rounds` then utilise `Enumerable.Reverse(...)`:

```
foreach (Round round in Enumerable.Reverse(Competition.Rounds)){...}
```

or less efficient alternative:

```
foreach (String round in Competition.Rounds.ToArray().Reverse()){...}
```